# How to deploy a Yii app to appFog

Tags: php, yii, cloud-hosting, appfog

I wanted to try the appFog free plan to tryout my application I developed in Yii,I checked the jumpstart on [appFog](http://appfog.com) section that says that Yii applications are now supported by appFog

However I have checked all the documentations about framework, only drupal and wordpress were available, I searched all over the internet but I couldn't find the best docs for it

Then I decided to try to upload both Yii framework folder and my application and include an index.php file that includes the myapplication/index.php file, which seemed to be a nice try but some assest and other classes in yii are configured to look for yii framework in the root directory causing my application to crash with Yii error but not php error

If anyone has already tried or know where I can find a nice tutorial about Yii on appfog, I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to deploy a test app without doing anything tricky:

1. Create a new php APP on AWS US East infrastruture from the appfog console
2. Download the latest [Yii tarball](http://www.yiiframework.com/download/) and extract it to a FOLDER
3. Create test application:

   ```
   $ cd FOLDER/framework
   $ ./yiic webapp ../testdrive
   ```
4. Push the changes:

   ```
   $ af update APP

   Uploading Application:
   Checking for available resources: OK
   Processing resources: OK
   Packing application: OK
   Uploading (71K): OK
   Push Status: OK
   Stopping Application 'APP': OK
   Staging Application 'APP': OK
   Starting Application 'APP': OK
   ```
5. Open http://APP.aws.af.cm/testdrive/ in browser:

   ```
   Welcome to My Web Application

   Congratulations! You have successfully created your Yii application.
   ```

Comment: How do account for assets and runtime directories that need to be writable?

Comment: Unfortunately, as of now [(but apparently on the way)](http://blog.appfog.com/how-to-use-amazon-s3-for-persistent-file-storage-on-appfog/), it is not possible to write any persistent changes to the filesystem. You'll have to commit changes locally before pushing, or use an S3 bucket or something similar.

Comment: @BonjourTristesse,thanks a lot,but the link you posted doesnt work,and i wonder in which folder you were in when you issued AF PUSH..because this will upload the framework content if you were in framework but not the app itself..if you were in folder again it will upload app only but not the framework..if you did the af update APP again..which one did you upload first framework or app?..thx

Comment: @BonjourTristesse,i think you were right and sorry for this question,the problem was that i ve never checked the changes to be made in the app in order to deploy your app..here are is good link about it http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/final.deployment